# Content Search Webpart Not Working

Tags: web-part, search, office-365

I am trying to add a Content Search Webpart in my office 365 Site Collection Page . I was able to configure the query and was able to see the results in the query builder Window. Now when i Apply the changes to the web part. There are no results getting Displayed . On Debugging the page, i found the error "**Search-Driven content (592CCB4A-9304-49AB-AAB1-66638198BB58) feature needs to be activated to use this Web Part."**

My site is a Team site template with Publishing features enabled. Another thing is , I have another tenant where everything related to this works.

> Things done :

- Enable Search Server Web Parts and Templates
- Enable Search Engine Sitemap
- Tried Enabling Cross site publishing feature, but it again threw error saying it needs the search driven content feature activated.

Any Help would be highly appreciated ?

Comment: Try enabling that feature using Powershell. Refer: http://www.kbasrai.com/b/2013/10/08/managing-features-in-office-365-via-powershell

Comment: I have enabled using Powershell but still wouldnt

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because the **Subscription Plan in the Tenant site does not Support Content Search Web Parts.** 
May be the error should have been “ Your Subscription plan cannot activate the feature.” :)

> Learning : Check the Service Description of the SharePoint o365 Plans before troubleshooting .

Comment: Is (SPOnline) Search accessible through the API?

Comment: All the Plans do support Search Rest API .